# Java Jqgrid and JSON Data not displayed

Tags: jsp

I have already tried and searched a lot for the solution but without results. I am trying to display JSON Data in my Jqgrid und it is not working. I have tried it with the same data and **datatype : 'jsonstring',**, which is working!
But I need to load the JSON Data from the URL and use dynamic loading. Here is my code:

```
var jQuery_1_8_3 = $.noConflict(true);    
jQuery_1_8_3(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery_1_8_3("#z-jqgrid-json-aj").jqGrid({
            url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getProducts',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            page: 1,
            jsonReader: {root: "products", cell: "cell"},
            colNames : ${prodConfigColNames},
            colModel : [ {
                name : '${prodColNames.get(0)}',
                index : '${prodColNames.get(0)}',
                sortable:false
            }, {
                name : '${prodColNames.get(1)}',
                index : '${prodColNames.get(1)}',
                sorttype : 'int'
            }, {
                name : '${prodColNames.get(2)}',
                index : '${prodColNames.get(2)}',
                align : 'right',
                sorttype : 'text'
            }, {
                name : '${prodColNames.get(3)}',
                index : '${prodColNames.get(3)}',
                align : 'right',
                sortable:false
            }, {
                name : '${prodColNames.get(4)}',
                index : '${prodColNames.get(4)}',
                align : 'right',
                sorttype : 'text'
            }, {
                name : '${prodColNames.get(5)}',
                index : '${prodColNames.get(5)}',
                sorttype : 'float'
            } ],
            pager : '#z-jqgrid-pager-json-aj',
            rowNum : 10,
            loadonce: false,
            ignoreCase: true,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            caption : 'JSONExample'
        });
```

And my data looks like that:

```
{"currpage":"1","totalpages":"10","totalrecords":"100","products":[{"id":1,"cell":["A","A","A"]},{"id":2,"cell":["B","B","B"]},{"id":3,"cell":["C","C","C"]},{"id":4,"cell":["D","D","D"]},{"id":5,"cell":["E","E","E"]},{"id":6,"cell":["F","F","F"]}]}
```

I can call the URL in my browser and I am able to see the JSON data.

I would be very thankful for your help.

here is my html:

```
<div>
<table id="z-jqgrid-json-aj">
</table>
<div id="z-jqgrid-pager-json-aj"></div>
```

I can only see a empty table. Here is how it looks like:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3UAt.jpg)

Comment: Have you kept the javascript for jqgrid in js file or jsp file?

Comment: It is in the jsp file. The java script is executing without any errors. But there is only a empty table visible. It is also loading the json Data, but not displaying it.